# Force certain windows 10 apps to use specific network card

Tags: windows, networking

I have 2 internet connections, a low speed low latency VDSL2 connection and a high speed high latency 4G connection (I live in a rural area of England)

I have all my wifi things on the 4G and use the DSL purely for gaming.  Sometimes though, I would like to download windows updates or other stuff on my PC without it killing online games.

I have the dsl connected to an ethernet port and I get on the 4G via the inbuilt wifi card.

Currently I've been enabling/disabling either the wifi or the ethernet card to switch

My question is this, is there a way or an app I can use to force say windows update can only use the wifi or Warzone can only use the DSL for game traffic?

Comment: As well as the dupes check out https://superuser.com/search?q=program+specific+network